# Vee-validate - validate repeatable input fields

Tags: vue.js, repeater, vee-validate

I want to validate a repeatable text field in vee-validate. At least one row of inputs should be filled. How can I achieve such kind of validation?

Here is shown how my repeatable text field looks like in the browser. When I click "+" a new row with inputs is added.

[image]

I will be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Sure, that seems possible? What did you try? Seems that if you give each input a unique name and apply v-validate as you would normally, it will work.

Comment: But these fields are generated dynamically. And I want also to ensure that at least one row of fields is filled.

Comment: Please check out the Stack Overflow FAQ - [This part specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  I suggest additionally you prepare an example perhaps using this as a template: https://codesandbox.io/s/x4kp93w3o

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the `required` rule only in the first row. If you have `v-for` in your code, you can use `track-by="$index"` to track the first row, and conditionally apply the rule.

However, I think if you add a code example, it would be really useful to others to help you.